# Blazor Wasm Hosted Prerender with Authentication AuthenticationStateProvider not registered

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-hosted

I have an out of the box VS Template using Blazor WebAssembly Hosted with Authentication and have converted it over to use PreRendering. However, in doing so it looks like there are a lot of services that are included in the client side that are not provided on the server side.   Here is the exception

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState'.
> There is no registered service of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent component)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing InvalidOperationException: Cannot
> provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState'.
> There is no registered service of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent component)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, Type componentType)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(ref
> RenderTreeFrame frame, int parentComponentId)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(ref
> DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(ref
> DiffContext diffContext, int frameIndex)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(ref
> DiffContext diffContext, int newFrameIndex)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(ref
> DiffContext diffContext, int oldStartIndex, int oldEndIndexExcl, int
> newStartIndex, int newEndIndexExcl)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer
> renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, int componentId,
> ArrayRange oldTree, ArrayRange
> newTree)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder
> batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry
> renderQueueEntry)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception
> exception)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int
> componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception
> exception)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView
> parameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int
> componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type
> componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type
> componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11+<b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView
> parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedWebAssemblyComponentAsync(HttpContext
> context, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object
> parameters)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext
> context, TagHelperOutput output)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task
> task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
> BBQFriend.Server.Pages.Pages__Host.b__9_1() in
> _Host.cshtml
> +
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
> BBQFriend.Server.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService
> events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

What services can I register in the Server startup.cs to Register the necessary services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been faced to the same issue and I resolved it in [TheIdServer](https://github.com/Aguafrommars/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer/Startup.cs) by registring and stubing some services :

```cs
services.AddRemoteAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, OidcProviderOptions>();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RemoteAuthenticationService>()
    .AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>()
    .AddTransient<IAccessTokenProvider, AccessTokenProvider>()
    .AddTransient<Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime, JSRuntime>();
```

**RemoteAuthenticationService.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Aguacongas.TheIdServer.Services
{
    public class RemoteAuthenticationService : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, IRemoteAuthenticationService<RemoteAuthenticationState>
    {

        public Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> CompleteSignInAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
        {
            return Success(context);
        }

        public Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> CompleteSignOutAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
        {
            return Success(context);
        }

        public Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> SignInAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
        {
            return Success(context);
        }

        public Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> SignOutAsync(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
        {
            return Success(context);
        }

        private static Task<RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>> Success(RemoteAuthenticationContext<RemoteAuthenticationState> context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new RemoteAuthenticationResult<RemoteAuthenticationState>
            {
                State = context.State,
                Status = RemoteAuthenticationStatus.Success
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**AccessTokenProvider.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Aguacongas.TheIdServer.Services
{
    public class AccessTokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        public ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ValueTask<AccessTokenResult> RequestAccessToken(AccessTokenRequestOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**JSRuntime.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Aguacongas.TheIdServer.Services
{
    public class JSRuntime : IJSRuntime
    {
        public ValueTask<TValue> InvokeAsync<TValue>(string identifier, object[] args)
        {
            return new ValueTask<TValue>();
        }

        public ValueTask<TValue> InvokeAsync<TValue>(string identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, object[] args)
        {
            return new ValueTask<TValue>();
        }
    }
}
```

I also remove :

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
```

from the blazor app's *Program.cs*

Comment: thank you so much this helped move me forward!

Answer (score 3):

So the answer is by adding `services.AddApiAuthorization();` to the Server `Startup.cs`

This fixes the issue with the missing service registrations, however, there is an additional error after.   From what it currently looks like, pre rendering is not supported with authentication.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued during server-side prerendering, because the page has not yet loaded in the browser. Prerendered components must wrap any JavaScript interop calls in conditional logic to ensure those interop calls are not attempted during prerendering.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.UnsupportedJavaScriptRuntime.Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync(string identifier, object[] args)